# Gorilla Session - Session per User

Tags: go, authentication, session, session-cookies, gorilla

When using gorilla sessions, every example I have seen does some variant of the following:

```
    var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(os.Getenv("SESSION_KEY")))

    func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Get a session. We're ignoring the error resulted from decoding an
        // existing session: Get() always returns a session, even if empty.
        session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")
        // Set some session values.
        session.Values["foo"] = "bar"
        session.Values[42] = 43
        // Save it before we write to the response/return from the handler.
        err := session.Save(r, w)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }
```

I have done this as well in my code, and it works. What I am confused about is `session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")`. It is a hard coded value which will always retrieve the same session.

To verify this I had 2 incognito browsers create a session with the ID of the user as a value within the session's value map. Both browsers returned the values of the last user to create the session. This all makes sense to me since we're using the same session name for everything.

**My question is the following**
To get a session per authenticated user, do I need to dynamically set the session name myself (probably with some info from the authenticated user itself)? If so, how would I be able to retrieve that information when the user accesses the site the next time and I need to retrieve info from the session store yet again?

Or am I thinking of sessions in the wrong way completely? This is my first time trying to create something with sessions so I have a strong feeling that I'm missing some basic concept.

Comment: oh my god! Thank you, I just tested this and it worked. Bah! I should have done 1 incognito window and 1 regular one to verify it. Thank you for sharing. If you want, copy and paste that comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie is used to identify the session or store the session data depending on the session store used. Two incognito windows in the same browser instance share the same cookies and therefore will share the same session. Try one of of the following: compare sessions in different browser instances (see browser command line help for how to start separate instances), compare sessions between incognito and non-incognito, compares sessions between Edge and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

A session variable contains several data, including the session start time. Interest Determine when the session ends.
This means that the session token differs even on the same browser and some window. Because the same user cannot login more than once at the same time.
However, this will still be known to all browsers. Because it carries the same data for the same user, for example the unique name or email.

`sess,_ := session.Get ("session-name", c)` used for session types. Set it dynamically only if you have multiple types of sessions.

`sess.Values ["email"] = email` Used to serve to find out who is connected to the user? These must be determined dynamically. It is set with a unique value such as Email or Id.
A range of data can be stored to customize the user experience. For example: Name, color, language. They advise against storing passwords. It encrypts sensitive data. Before set.

This is a simple senario of gorilla session:

```golang
func initSession(c echo.Context, name, email string) {
      sess, _ := session.Get("session-name", c) // session_name like: addmin_sess of user_ses or onything.
      sess.Options = &sessions.Options{
          Path:     "/",
          MaxAge:   216000,           // = 1h,
          HttpOnly: true,             // no websocket or any protocol else
      }
  
      sess.Values["email"] = email      // nessessary in this senario
      sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())
  }
  
  func login(c echo.Context) error {
      formEmail := c.FormValue("email")
      formPass := c.FormValue("password")
      email, pass := getUsername(formEmail)  // "select email pass from UserTable where email_field == formEmail"
   
       if pass == formPass && email == formEmail {
           initSession(c, email)    // set session of this uniq user in browser. 
           return c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, "/")  // login success.
       }
       return c.Render(200, "login.html", "Username or password is wrong")
   }
```

The user cannot access the <profile page> without logging in:

```golang
func profilePage(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session_name", c)

    email := sess.Values["email"]  // we get email from browser.
    if email == nil {
        return c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, "/login") // login firs.
    }

    return c.Render(200, "profile.html", email) // just show email
}
```